# How to Decrypt, incryptdumpfile in mysql using C# (MySqlBackup.dll)

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to Decrypt the Mysql Incrypted dump file with mysqlbackup.dll. I use `bc.DecryptDumpFile()` but this show error "Incorrect password or corrupted context" How to decrypt this file

```
MySqlBackup bc = new MySqlBackup();
bc.DecryptDumpFile(Application.StartupPath + "//POS_Assistant - 24-Jul-19.dll", Application.StartupPath + "//POS.sql", "Rehman92");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below code helps:

```
   private void DecryptDumpFile()
    {
        string oldDumpFile = "C:\\backup.sql";
        string newDumpFile = "C:\\backup_new.sql";
        MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup();
        mb.EnableEncryption = true;
        mb.EncryptionKey = "qwerty";
        mb.DecryptSqlDumpFile(oldDumpFile, newDumpFile);
    }
```

Comment: Which version of mysql backup you using ? are you test this code ? This is not working for me

Comment: If this work for you i will send you encrypted file can you decrypt it for me?